# Component memoized with React.memo() keeps re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ParentComponent` looking like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  [product, setProduct] = useState({
    name: "Test",
    description: "Information goes here..."
  })

  return(
    <ChildComponent product={product} updateProduct={setProduct}/>
  );
}
```

and a `ChildComponent` as follows:

```
const ChildComponent = ({product, updateProduct}) => {
  // some code here

  return(
    <RichTextEditor content={product.description} update={updateProduct}/>
  )
}

const isEqual = () => {
  return true; // I want to force the component to never re-render
}

export default React.memo(ChildComponent, isEqual)
```

What's happening here is that I have a `product` object with a description that is updated by the `ChildComponent`. The value for the description gets set via `updateProduct` every time the input changes in the `RichTextEditor` component. I understand that because of the state change of `product` the `ChildComponent` gets re-rendered everytime which is unfortunate because that can cause unwanted effects like making the input field inside `RichTextEditor` lose focus for example. So I tried forcing the `ChildComponent` to never re-render with my `isEqual` function that always returns true. It keeps re-rendering though, why is that?

I realize that there are other designs available to avoid this issue completely, and I'm probably going to do that anyways but before I do that I want to understand why I can not force `ChildComponent` to not re-render.

Comment: Are you using useState or useContext inside ChildComponent?

Comment: @RaduDiță yes I am

Comment: Then that's the reason why you are getting re-renders. React.memo only works on props, if you have other reason for re-rendering (useState/useContext/useReducer) it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `useState`, `useContext` or `useReducer` then the component will still re-render.

This is straight from the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20function%20component%20wrapped%20in%20React.memo%20has%20a%20useState%2C%20useReducer%20or%20useContext%20Hook%20in%20its%20implementation%2C%20it%20will%20still%20rerender%20when%20state%20or%20context%20change.).

Comment: It will not re-render simply because you are using those hooks. It should only re-render if the state or the context changes

`"React.memo only checks for prop changes. If your function component wrapped in React.memo has a useState, useReducer or useContext Hook in its implementation, it will still rerender when state or context change."`

Answer (score 0):

Does your child component use any context?

Even when a component is memoized, it will still re-render when a context that it’s using changes. Memoization only has to do with props that are passed to the component from its parent.

To solve this, pass your context value into your component by props, not use context directly inside your child component.